# Query on non key in Redis

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, node-redis

I am storing objects as hash ,for example: key-> customer:123 ,email->dk@gmail.com,mobile->828212,name->darshan etc...

Now is it possible in redis to query customers based on email without storing the cross relationship as set which is more of a workaround.
like for example,at the time of insertion of customer storing Set as key->email:dk@gmail.com value->customer:123 and so on.
Lets say if I have 100 fields in a hash, and i need to query 20 of them(like email)
it increases the count of keys in redis instance significantly if we create each entry of those fields in Sets as well.

Is there any other alternative or better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis doesn't have inbuilt indexing/searching by fields because it is not a database but more like a data structures server(each key holds a data structure like set/list/map/sortedset/number of unique values etc), but if you are using redis 4.0 you can use the search module to accomplish it. The link is [here](http://redisearch.io/).

Comment: This is worth giving a try...bt what abt performance will it scale as good as query on key attribute or even close to it ?

Comment: Of course, it gives very good performance because everything can be indexed. The only problem that i know is that it will work well for a single redis instance, but the cluster support for redisearch is only planned for enterprise redis.

Comment: The website mentions indexes only for List,Sets,sorted sets.There is no explanation about implementing secondary indexes on fields of Hash data structure